# Integral $\int_0^1 [\ln(x)]^n dx = (-1)^n n! $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$I_n=\int_0^1  [\ln(x)]^n dx = (-1)^n n! $$ The integration bounds doesn't make any sense to me, I tried integration by parts setting
$$
u=[\ln(x)]^n,\quad dv=dx , \quad I_n = x(\ln(x))^n\big|_0^1 - I_{n-1}  
$$
and then I did the $I_{n-1}$ by parts the same way as in $I_n$.

The problem is with the part "$x(\ln(x))^n\big|_0^1$":
what is this supposed to equal to ???

Comment: Check the edited version I hope I clarified it enough

Comment: Refer gamma function

Answer (score 4):

$x (\ln x)^{n} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ but I suggest the following method: The substitution $y =-\ln x$ reduces the integral to $(-1)^{n} \int_0^{\infty} y^{n} e^{-y}dy$. We can evaluate the last integral by repeated integration by parts. Its value is $n!$.

Answer (score 4):

If $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then the proof is trivial

$$\int_0^1 x^{a-1}\ln^n(x)dx=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial a^n}\int_0^1 x^{a-1}dx=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial a^n}\cdot \frac1a=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{a^{n+1}}$$

Set $a=1$ we have

$$\int_0^1 \ln^n(x)dx=(-1)^n n!$$

Comment: I think I need more clarification on why the first statement is true  $$\int_0^1 x^{a-1}\ln^n(x)dx=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial a^n}\int_0^1 x^{a-1}dx$$

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} x^{a-1}=x^{a-1} \ln x ,\ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2} x^{a-1}= x^{a-1} \ln ^2x, ...$

Answer (score 0):

substituting $u=-ln(x)$ gives $$-1^n\int_0^\infty u^ne^{-u}du$$ the integral is known as the gamma function $$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx=(x-1)!$$ applying the knowledge to the integral we get $$\int^1_0 [ln(x)]^ndx=(-1)^nn!$$